# Expressing the duration of an action

Tags: grammar

The question is so basic that I'm not even sure how to express the nature of my problem. Still, it confounded me to the point I just had to ask it here.

Is there **any** grammar issue in any of the following sentences? Or are they all considered correct and idiomatic English?

> 1. I'm here for just a month.
> 2. I'm staying here for a month.
> 3. I will stay here for a month.
> 4. I am going to stay here for a month.
> 5. I will be staying here for a month.

I'm asking mainly because I've found an opinion on another language forum, stating that both 1. and 3. sound awkward - yet I can't understand why.

Comment: My first thought was that [*I'm **only** here for a month*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I%27m+only+here+for+a+month%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) seems far more "natural" to me than any of these suggestions. Checking Google Books I find it occurs 122 times, but there's only a single written instance of [*I'm here for **just** a month*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I%27m+here+for+just+a+month%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). But I can't see any *grammatical* arguments against any of the alternatives - it's just idiomatic/stylistic preference.

Comment: But would you go as far as to say that the other options aren't sentences you'd use? Do they strike you as unnatural, as for a native speaker?

Comment: By "another language forum", do you mean this: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100625000451AAaViAp?

Comment: Nope; speaking of the third clause, this was the source of my concern: http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1394019&langid=21

What's wrong with that Yahoo link anyway?

Comment: @BebopB. Nothing. (I haven't read the answers there anyway.) But the situation in that question is different from yours. In that question, the situation is: "Suppose you were in a foreign country. You were supposed to stay there for a month. it had passed for ten days since you came there."

Comment: The only one I'd question is #3. It sounds to my ear like a foreigner speaking English. #5 is its idiomatic cousin.  *I shall stay here for a month* is its Edwardian English ancestor. That said, as part of an itinerary, it is perfectly idiomatic: "I will stay *here* for a month, and then fly out to Chicago."

Comment: @Bebop B.: I've no doubt *over a lifetime* I've used every one of these variants at least several times (not necessarily *for a month*, but certainly once we include *for a few minutes, days, a week,* etc.). As Iplodman says, there's nothing "wrong" with any of them. I'm sure TRomano will reconsider and allow that *"I'll stay here for a bit"* is 100% natural, and said by countless people every day. And if we're going to split hairs about whether the contraction is *required* to prevent it being "awkward", I think this is all just a matter of opinions.

Comment: Well, God, I can't believe that this is the case. I wouldn't suppose a simple lack of contraction could change the reception of these sentences this much. Thank you! I thought there was something wrong with my understanding of grammar, while in fact the answer is just as simple as the question itself :D

Comment: All are okay, if you are concerned about grammar.

Comment: I'm concerned both about grammar and the idiomatic meaning.

Comment: Not everything that is grammatical is idiomatic, but everything that is idiomatic is grammatical.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm well aware of this fact. Supposing they are all fitted with proper contractions, do you think any of these sentences is not idiomatic? I feel that your comment is quite equivocal.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't say that either is *wrong*, but 1 could do with some improvement. I'd recommend changing it to:

> I'm just here for a month.

A likely reason that the third sentence sounds 'wrong' to the other person is that "I will" hasn't been shortened to "I'll", like it commonly is. I'd recommend shortening your "I will" and "I am"s to "I'll" and "I'm"s respectively.

Comment: Doesn't replacing words in the first sentence impact the meaning, changing it slightly? And why is shortening so important in these cases?

Comment: @BebopB. Because the only difference between these two sentences and the others is that they are less colloquial than the others -- which seems a little odd in a first person statement. Contraction eliminates this distinction.

Comment: Huh, I thought I'd commented already. Nevermind, @StoneyB put it much better than me anyway!